# Refresh the wordpress home page Automatically

Tags: wordpress, refresh

How can i refresh the Homepage automatically every 3 minutes?

I only want the index.php and not all the pages (will not place the code in header.php).

What is the code I should use and where to place? here's my index.php first lines:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Default_Theme
 */

get_header(); 
?>
<!--Body Container Start Here -->
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what your theme is like, but you can use a hook, like wp_head and check for conditions you want. This can be inserted in functions.php or elsewhere.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Default_Theme
 */

function check_if_this_is_home_and_then() {
    if( is_home() ) {

?>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180;url=http://stackoverflow.com/">

<?php

    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'check_if_this_is_home_and_then' );

get_header(); 
?>

<!--Body Container Start Here -->
```

Comment: My Homepage starts with this `<?php
/**
 * package WordPress
 * subpackage Default_Theme
 */

get_header(); 
?>
<!--Body Container Start Here -->

<div class="body-Container">
  <!--body left panel -->
  <div class="body-left-panel right">
    <!--Special Topics -->
    <div class="special-topic-container">
      <?php 
//========================================START Special Topics Fetching according to Status==========================`

Comment: But I am confused. What to do actually? I am not very good with wordpress.

Comment: Plop just (1) that function and (2) add_action line into functions.php (no get_header(), no @package comment, nothing else), and it will just magically work across the site.  Alternatively, you could turn this into a plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a meta refresh tag only on your home page?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180;url=http://stackoverflow.com/">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where do I put this in the header?

Comment: @pp19dd showed you a good solution where you check if it is your home page and if that is the case it renders the refresh meta tag. All this goes in your header. Please check his solution!

Comment: I tried the code below in the header.php and when I went to single after 3 minutes I got redirected to the homepage.

Comment: Try this, it is straight from the Wordpress Codex which is incredibly useful! 

<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
   

?>
 put your meta refresh here
<?php
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
?>

For testing purposes put a smaller number for the refresh.. let's say 2 seconds.

Comment: Bro this is hard. Where to place this? and what about //this is not a homepage?

Comment: Place this in your header file but before the get_header function!
If this doesn't work, try to place this before your code:

wp_reset_query();

Comment: So I place this code am i right at the top? I couldn't find get_header... 

`<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180;url=http://stackoverflow.com/"> <?php } else { // This is not a homepage } ?>`

P.S: Every time I click on enter the post gets published. How to fix that here? so if I click on enter I get to a new line? 


Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Holding shift+enter will go to the next line. That code you pasted there seems okay to me. Does it work?

Comment: Hi thanks it worked ;) but I had to remove this 

// this is not a homepage

So my code is `<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180;url=http://stackoverflow.com/"> <?php } else { } ?> `

Is that good? or bad php code?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following;

```
<script language="JavaScript">
     var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname);
     var intValue = 0;
     function doLoad()
     {
         intValue=setTimeout( "refresh()", 300*1000 );
     }

    function refresh()
     {
         window.location.href = sURL;
     }

    function noRefresh(e)
     {
         switch (e.keyCode) {
             case 40:
             case 39:
             case 38:
             case 37:
             case 34:
             case 33:
                 break;
             default:
                 clearTimeout(intValue);
         }

    }

    if ($.browser.mozilla) {
         $(document).keypress(noRefresh);
     } else {
         $(document).keydown(noRefresh);
     }

    $(document).ready(doLoad());
 </script>
 <noscript>
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
 </noscript>
```

As above, amending the 300 within `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">` to say 60, would refresh this every 60 seconds.

Hope that works!

**EDIT: This would be amended within your 'header.php' :)